# urllib2 File Download Fails...due to System Security?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to download files (approximately 1 - 1.5MB/file) from a NASA server ([URL](http://avdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=list&path=/H2O//2010)), but to no avail!  I've tried a few things with urllib2 and run into two results:

1. I create a new file on my machine that is only ~200KB and has nothing in it
2. I create a 1.5MB file on my machine that has nothing in it!

By "nothing in it" I mean when I open the file (these are hdf5 files, so I open them in hdfView) I see no hierarchical structure...literally looks like an empty h5 file.  But, when I open the file in a text editor I can see there is SOMETHING there (it's binary, so in text it looks like...well, binary).

I think I am using urllib2 appropriately, though I have never successfully used urllib2 before.  Would you please comment on whether what I am doing is right or not, and suggest something better?

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
base_url = 'http://avdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=list&path=%2FH2O%2F/2010'
file_name = 'download_2.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=download&path=%2FH2O%2F2010&file=MLS-Aura_L2GP-H2O_v03-31-c01_2010d360.he5'


url = base_url + file_name
req = Request(url)

# Open the url
try:
    f = urlopen(req)
    print "downloading " + url

    # Open our local file for writing
    local_file = open('test.he5', "w" + file_mode)
    #Write to our local file
    local_file.write(f.read())
    local_file.close()

except HTTPError, e:
    print "HTTP Error:",e.code , url
except URLError, e:
    print "URL Error:",e.reason , url
```

I got this script (which seems to be the closest to working) from [here](http://www.techniqal.com/blog/2008/07/31/python-file-read-write-with-urllib2/).
I am unsure what the file_name should be.  I looked at the page source information of the archive and pulled the file name listed there (not the same as what shows up on the web page), and doing this yields the 1.5MB file that shows nothing in hdfview.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an invalid url:

```
base_url = 'http://avdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=list&path=%2FH2O%2F/2010'
file_name = 'download_2.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=download&path=%2FH2O%2F2010&file=MLS-Aura_L2GP-H2O_v03-31-c01_2010d360.he5'

url = base_url + file_name
```

You probably meant:

```
base_url = 'http://avdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/'
file_name = 'download_2.php?site=1480884223&id=40&go=download&path=%2FH2O%2F2010&file=MLS-Aura_L2GP-H2O_v03-31-c01_2010d360.he5'
```

When downloading a large file, it's better to use a buffered copy from filehandle to filehandle:

```
import shutil

# ...
f = urlopen(req)
with open('test.he5', "w" + file_mode) as local_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, local_file)
```

[`.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) will efficiently load from the open urllib connection and write to the open `local_file` file handle. Note the `with` statement, when the code block underneath concludes it'll automatically close the file for you.

Comment: D'oh, that works.  Thanks for the help.  
By the way, how did you know the url was invalid?

Comment: @tnknepp: I checked the page you linked after seeing your definition for `base` and `file_name`. You normally do not append things to a URL that ends in a set of query parameters (the `?...` part) with something that starts with a path and it's own query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I like the buffered option much better.  I'll definitely get some good use out of this.